# Why is EntityFramework code first ignoring key value set in code

Tags: .net, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I have created a basic Entity Framework test project which is making use of the Code-First approach to populate a database which has two tables.

However, I have noticed that the framework seems to be automatically assigning a value to an entry which is used as a foreign key to another table, despite the fact that I have already set the value in code.

When inspecting via the debugger I can see that the object's property is correct until the point the SaveChanges() is called, but on inspecting the database, the int which I set has been overwritten with an automatically-generated value.

I can get around this by applying the following attribute to the property:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

However, I thought that values were only automatically-generated if no value had been set in code. Am I wrong, or is such behaviour to be expected?

I have noticed that the same behaviour isn't true for a primary key which isn't acting as a foreign key.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more, but I'm going to guess.  You are setting the [Key] attribute on your foreign key column?  If so, then don't.  From my understanding, [Key] is for primary key, and should not be used to define a foreign key.

Comment: Thanks for that, although I wasn't adding any attribute to the property until I encountered the problem.

Comment: If I remove [Key] it doesn't work - the value which I have set is ignored, and a value for the property is auto-generated instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Key]
>   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Annotation or Fluent API equivalent is required if using Key int Id and you wish to supply the Id.

[Ef Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583) default behaviour for Id int

Comment: That explanation is certainly consistent with the behaviour which I've seen - int key values which I've supplied are overwritten unless the above attributes are applied. The foreign key bit was a red-herring; where a key value wasn't being overwritten a string was being used rather than an int.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Attempting to add records causes a `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TableName' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`